# Set unix timestamp (int) as TIMESTAMP COLUMN in QuestDB

Tags: questdb

I have created a table coming from CSV upload which has a unix timestamp in the form of `1613775600`. At import phase, QuestDB casts it as `Int`.

How can I set this field as the `TIMESTAMP` column ?

I tried this in my SELECT:

```
cast(unixDate AS TIMESTAMP)
```

but it does not correctly parses the unix date, giving inconsistent dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like seconds precision. QuestDb timestamp is in microseconds this cast should work

```
cast(unixDate * 1000000L AS TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: Thanks, could you point me to the right directions in the docs to get this `1000000L`?Would love to see more of these formats for other similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

For now I used this trick:

```
dateadd('s', unixDate, to_timestamp('1970-01-01T00:00:00+0000', 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ'))
```

which basically adds `XXXXXXXXXX` seconds to the UTC date of `January 1st, 1970`.

Works quite well actually.